# How to Collapse already opened expansion Tiles after clicking on another expansion Tile in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

i am using multiple expansion tiles in my app. i need to close already opened tile after clicking on another. i have tried using expansion panel which by default having that functionality. But i need to re Design expansion tile so i am using expansion Tile. how to achieve that functionality in expansion tile

Comment: check this question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48930372/flutter-collapsing-expansiontile-after-choosing-an-item

Comment: checkout my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65857450/9960377 hope this will help you.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me in Bottom Sheet https://stackoverflow.com/a/65857450/13572333

Answer (score 12):

[This answer in GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7024#issuecomment-578124918) should do the trick.

Here is the sample:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'ExpansionTile Collapse',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'ExpansionTile Collapse'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  // selected's value = 0. For default first item is open.
  int selected = 0; //attention

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('ExpansionTile Collapse',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(children: [
            ListView.builder(
              key: Key('builder ${selected.toString()}'), //attention
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 13.0, right: 13.0, bottom: 25.0),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: 5,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Column(children: <Widget>[
                  Divider(
                    height: 17.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  ExpansionTile(
                    key: Key(index.toString()), //attention
                    initiallyExpanded: index == selected, //attention

                    leading: Icon(
                      Icons.person,
                      size: 50.0,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    title: Text('ExpansionTile ${index}',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xFF09216B),
                            fontSize: 17.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      'Software Engineer',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 13.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                        child: Text(
                          'DETAİL ${index} \n' + 'Expanded',
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                    onExpansionChanged: ((newState) {
                      if (newState)
                        setState(() {
                          Duration(seconds: 20000);
                          selected = index;
                        });
                      else
                        setState(() {
                          selected = -1;
                        });
                    }),
                  ),
                ]);
              },
            )
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Actual output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would go for an ExpansionPanelList.radio, because in the above method you will loose the animation. Check out this link: [ExpansionPanelList.radio usage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanelList/ExpansionPanelList.radio.html).You don't have to keep track of the index, and it allows for at most one panel in the list to be open.