# Is there a way in Flutter to allow only one ExpansionTile of a dynamic generated ListView to be expanded?

Tags: flutter

Is there a way in Flutter to allow only one ExpansionTile of a dynamic generated ListView to be expanded?

E.g. my ListView has three ExpansionTiles and I click on the first one, it expands. Now, if I tap on the second one, the second one should expand whereas the first one should close itself.

In my head it should work like putting this task into the "onExpansionChanged" method but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't with Flutter's ExpansionTile but I created a CustomExpansionTile that allows this:

CustomExpansionTile:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Duration _kExpand = Duration(milliseconds: 200);

class CustomExpansionTile extends StatefulWidget {

  const CustomExpansionTile({
    Key key,
    this.leading,
    @required this.title,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.children = const <Widget>[],
    this.trailing,
    @required this.expandedItem,
  }) :  super(key: key);

  /// A widget to display before the title.
  ///
  /// Typically a [CircleAvatar] widget.
  final Widget leading;

  /// The primary content of the list item.
  ///
  /// Typically a [Text] widget.
  final Widget title;

  /// The widgets that are displayed when the tile expands.
  ///
  /// Typically [ListTile] widgets.
  final List<Widget> children;

  /// The color to display behind the sublist when expanded.
  final Color backgroundColor;

  /// A widget to display instead of a rotating arrow icon.
  final Widget trailing;

  final ValueNotifier<Key> expandedItem;

  @override
  _CustomExpansionTileState createState() => _CustomExpansionTileState();
}

class _CustomExpansionTileState extends State<CustomExpansionTile> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  static final Animatable<double> _easeOutTween = CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeOut);
  static final Animatable<double> _easeInTween = CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeIn);
  static final Animatable<double> _halfTween = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 0.5);

  final ColorTween _borderColorTween = ColorTween();
  final ColorTween _headerColorTween = ColorTween();
  final ColorTween _iconColorTween = ColorTween();
  final ColorTween _backgroundColorTween = ColorTween();

  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _iconTurns;
  Animation<double> _heightFactor;
  Animation<Color> _borderColor;
  Animation<Color> _headerColor;
  Animation<Color> _iconColor;
  Animation<Color> _backgroundColor;

  bool _isExpanded = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(duration: _kExpand, vsync: this);
    _heightFactor = _controller.drive(_easeInTween);
    _iconTurns = _controller.drive(_halfTween.chain(_easeInTween));
    _borderColor = _controller.drive(_borderColorTween.chain(_easeOutTween));
    _headerColor = _controller.drive(_headerColorTween.chain(_easeInTween));
    _iconColor = _controller.drive(_iconColorTween.chain(_easeInTween));
    _backgroundColor = _controller.drive(_backgroundColorTween.chain(_easeOutTween));

    _isExpanded =  widget.expandedItem.value == widget.key;
    if (_isExpanded)
      _controller.value = 1.0;

    widget.expandedItem.addListener(listener);
  }

  void listener() {
    setState(() {
      _changeState(widget.expandedItem.value == widget.key);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    widget.expandedItem.removeListener(listener);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _changeState(bool isExpanded) {
    setState(() {
      _isExpanded = isExpanded;
      if (_isExpanded) {
        _controller.forward();
      } else {
        _controller.reverse().then<void>((void value) {
          if (!mounted)
            return;
          setState(() {
            // Rebuild without widget.children.
          });
        });
      }
      PageStorage.of(context)?.writeState(context, _isExpanded);
    });
  }

  void _handleTap() {
    _changeState(!_isExpanded);
    widget.expandedItem.value = _isExpanded ? widget.key : null;
  }

  Widget _buildChildren(BuildContext context, Widget child) {
    final Color borderSideColor = _borderColor.value ?? Colors.transparent;

    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: _backgroundColor.value ?? Colors.transparent,
        border: Border(
          top: BorderSide(color: borderSideColor),
          bottom: BorderSide(color: borderSideColor),
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTileTheme.merge(
            iconColor: _iconColor.value,
            textColor: _headerColor.value,
            child: ListTile(
              onTap: _handleTap,
              leading: widget.leading,
              title: widget.title,
              trailing: widget.trailing ?? RotationTransition(
                turns: _iconTurns,
                child: const Icon(Icons.expand_more),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ClipRect(
            child: Align(
              heightFactor: _heightFactor.value,
              child: child,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    _borderColorTween
      ..end = theme.dividerColor;
    _headerColorTween
      ..begin = theme.textTheme.subhead.color
      ..end = theme.accentColor;
    _iconColorTween
      ..begin = theme.unselectedWidgetColor
      ..end = theme.accentColor;
    _backgroundColorTween
      ..end = widget.backgroundColor;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bool closed = !_isExpanded && _controller.isDismissed;
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _controller.view,
      builder: _buildChildren,
      child: closed ? null : Column(children: widget.children),
    );

  }

}
```

usage :

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:playground/custom_expansion_tile.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}



class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ValueNotifier<Key> _expanded = ValueNotifier(null);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          CustomExpansionTile(
            expandedItem: _expanded,
            key: Key('1'),
            title: Text('Title #1'),
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Child')
            ],
          ),
          CustomExpansionTile(
            expandedItem: _expanded,
            key: Key('2'),
            title: Text('Title #2'),
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Child')
            ],

          ),
          CustomExpansionTile(
            expandedItem: _expanded,
            key: Key('3'),
            title: Text('Title #3'),
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Child')
            ],

          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

note: you must give a unique Key to the `CustomExpansionTile`s for this to work

Comment: I try ExpandablePanelList to do perform expand and collapse view. It also work

Comment: This is great thank you!

Comment: What did you give the ```ValueNotifier<Key> _expanded = ValueNotifier(null);``` as casue I'm getting an error in NullSaftey

Comment: @niroop-nife, Note that the ValueNotifier can take any  type of value (Variable), for this case i will do : ValueNotifier<Key> _expanded = ValueNotifier(const Key("My_Key"));