# How to warn a user before closing the expansion tile by showing a popup message in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm learning about expansion tiles in flutter. Is there any way to show a pop up before closing the expansion tile? If ok is pressed close the expansion tile, if cancel is pressed retain the state of expansion tile. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ExpansionTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html) docs state that it has a property [`onExpansionChanged`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile/onExpansionChanged.html):

> Called when the tile expands or collapses.
>
> When the tile starts expanding, this function is called with the value true. When the tile starts collapsing, this function is called with the value false.

One way would be to combine this property (for example, whenever you receive `false`) with something like [`showDialog`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html):

> Displays a Material dialog above the current contents of the app, with Material entrance and exit animations, modal barrier color, and modal barrier behavior (dialog is dismissible with a tap on the barrier).

**Edit - addressing edited question:**

It seems that programatically expanding/collapsing `ExpansionTile` is somewhat problematic. There's an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7024) in Flutter repository for it.

However, I believe you could achieve what you seek by extending `ExpansionTile` as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48935106/4543382). It is a little involved, though.

Another way to do that would be employing [`ExpansionPanelList`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanelList-class.html) and [`ExapnsionPanels`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanel-class.html), as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51383677/4543382). I've included a working (but crude) proof-of-concept app below. Feel free to modify and adapt it to your needs.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Expanding panels',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool expanded = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Pushing data'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Card(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ExpansionPanelList(
                expansionCallback: (int index, bool status) {
                  if (status == true) {
                    showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return AlertDialog(
                          title: new Text('Alert Dialog'),
                          content: new Text('What do you want to do?'),
                          actions: <Widget>[
                            FlatButton(
                              child: Text('Cancel'),
                              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                            ),
                            FlatButton(
                              child: Text(
                                'Collapse',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  expanded = false;
                                });
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  } else {
                    setState(() {
                      expanded = true;
                    });
                  }
                },
                children: [
                  ExpansionPanel(
                    canTapOnHeader: true,
                    isExpanded: expanded,
                    headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool expanded) {
                      return Text('Expansion Panel Header');
                    },
                    body: Center(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Text('Expanded panel body'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried it. But before confirming the click on alert dialog the expansion tile is closed. I need to close the expansion tile when only the alert dialog is pressed ok and stay at the same state when clicked cancel on the alert dialog

Comment: Take a look at the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48935106/4543382. It discusses a way to extend `ExpansionTile` to have controllable expand/collapse/toggle behavior. I believe it might be useful for the issue you are facing.

Comment: I've added a working example and updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use it. Any widget that does not constraint vertical size should be usable with `ExpansionPanelList`.