# Colapse ExpansionTile when new ExpansionTile is expanded

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to solve this problem for a few hours but with no luck. I've seen similar question here but none of them seems to work for my case. Here is simplified code

```
static final List<String> _listViewData = [
    'Option1',
    'Option2',
    "Option3",
    "Option4",
    "Option5",
    "Option6",
    "Option7"
  ];


body: Container(
        height: 450,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _listViewData.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => ExpansionTile(
            subtitle: Text('description'),
            children: <Widget>[Text('expanded')],
            title: Text(_listViewData[index]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

So far when I chose Option1 from the list the Option1 will expand. When I then chose Option2, Option2 will expand but Option1 stays expanded. So how can I collapse expanded tile when new one is expanded?

Comment: have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59896985/12709039

Comment: It actually works but without animation... Still better then nothing.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to make it work but probably because of the setState it rebuilds the screen as the selected row is initially expanded. So the animation is not working. I think the solution is to write your own ExpansionTile and implement that feature. I will post it here if I do that

Comment: @SelimKundakçıoğlu  Also what I noticed that the solution in the link doesn't work with children like slider in your expansion title. I mean it works but slider doesn't. There is simple no way for now to use expansion title in this case I guess

Comment: Currently, I am trying to implement a package for that feature. I will post it here if I can so that you will be notified.