# How to Expand only one ExpansionTile at a time in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, expandablelistview

I have built a `Listview` with `ExpansionTile`. But Now I want that if I tap on an `ExpansionTile` then only that `ExpansionTile` should open and other Expanded `ExpansionTile` should close.

Please help me how can I achieve this?

Here is my Code for `ExpansionTile`

```
   @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Short Product"),
            ),
            body: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: Category_List.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                return ExpansionTile(
                  title: Text(Category_List[i].cat_name),
                  children:_Product_ExpandAble_List_Builder(Category_List[i].cat_id)
                );
              },
            )
         );
      }

      _Product_ExpandAble_List_Builder(int cat_id) {
        List<Widget> columnContent = [];
        Product_List.forEach((product) => {
                columnContent.add(
                  ListTile(
                    title: ExpansionTile(
                        title: Text(product.prod_name),
                        ),
                    trailing: Text("${product.total_Qty} (Kg)"),
                  ),
                ),
            });
        return columnContent;
      }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a little advice.. All variable should be formatted in camel case starting with lower case letter. I'm not sure if formatting variable names otherwise will have any affect on functionality of the app but most importantly it is the rule to format it that way

Comment: Just use a `ExpansionPanelList.radio` - it does what you want.

Comment: You can have a controller for each expansion tile and then using the controller you can manage the collapse and expand state.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can programmatically change expansion tile should open or close.

I made similar to your code.

```
int selected; //attention

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Short Product"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        key: Key('builder ${selected.toString()}'), //attention
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return ExpansionTile(
              key: Key(i.toString()), //attention
              initiallyExpanded: i == selected, //attention
              title: Text(i.toString()),
              children: _Product_ExpandAble_List_Builder(i),
              onExpansionChanged: ((newState) {
                if (newState)
                  setState(() {
                    selected = i;
                  });
                else
                  setState(() {
                    selected = -1;
                  });
              }));
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _Product_ExpandAble_List_Builder(int cat_id) {
    List<Widget> columnContent = [];
    [1, 2, 4, 5].forEach((product) => {
          columnContent.add(
            ListTile(
              title: ExpansionTile(
                title: Text(product.toString()),
              ),
              trailing: Text("$product (Kg)"),
            ),
          ),
        });
    return columnContent;
  }
```

Comment: Nice workaround almost same as this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59820265/i-want-first-expansiontiles-item-default-is-open-i-want-to-when-i-click-anothe/59896985#59896985 I think the right answer should be no it is not possible unless you create your own expansion tile. The build in expansion tiles aren't design to do this. Using this workarounds will damage all animations so it is quite useless unless you don't mind design. I'm waiting for this feature long time to be implemented into flutter expansion tile

Comment: Now i have a sublist how i can do this for that list??

Comment: setState changes scroll position, Is there any way to get rid of it?

Answer (score 3):

There is widget from Flutter team for this:

**ExpansionPanelList** with its **ExpansionPanelList.radio** builder

See docs

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanelList/ExpansionPanelList.radio.html