# allow only one ExpansionTile to be expanded

Tags: listview, flutter, flutter-layout

My question is:

Is there a way in Flutter to allow only one ExpansionTile of a dynamic generated ListView to be expanded?

E.g. my ListView has three ExpansionTiles and I click on the first one, it expands.  Now, if I tap on the second one, the second one should expand whereas the first one should close itself.

I thought of using this modified ExpansionTile (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48935106/3775957) but couldn't come up with a solution.

In my head it should work like putting this task into the "onExpansionChanged" method but I don't know how.

I build my ListView like this:

```
ListView.builder(
   itemCount: myArray.length,
   itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ExpansionTile(
             backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
                key: PageStorageKey('${myArray[index].name}'),
                title: Text(myArray[index].name),
                children: _buildChildrenWidgets(
                      groupName: myArray[index].name,
                      childrenNames: myArray[index].anotherArray),
                );
              });
```

Comment: you have `initiallyExpanded` in `ExpansionTile` constructor, so use it when creating a new `ExpansionTile`

Comment: I'm aware of that. All `ExpansionTile` s are created with the default value of `false` for `initiallyExpanded`. The problem is during runtime: when I tap on another Tile to expand it, the other expanded ones remain expanded. But I want them to close when another Tile expands.

Comment: so build your three `ExpansionTile`s on tap - two of them (not tapped) will have `initiallyExpanded: false` and tapped `ExpansionTile` will have `initiallyExpanded: true`

Comment: but isn't that heavy for the peformance to rebuild the layout everytime I tap on an `ExpansionTile`? 
Because my Tiles are not static, I load the values for them from a json-file with a `FutureBuilder` - also, `ExpansionTile` has no `onTap` like `ListTile` or `InkWell`

Comment: no - it will not hurt the performance, also it has `onExpansionChanged`

Comment: so I assume it is right to somehow use `onExpansionChanged`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ExpansionPanelList`
like this

```
 ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
                    return Card(
                      child: ExpansionPanelList(
                        expansionCallback: (int index, bool status) {
                          setState(() {
                            _activeMeterIndex =
                                _activeMeterIndex == i ? null : i;
                          });
                        },
                        children: [
                          ExpansionPanel(
                            isExpanded: _activeMeterIndex == i,
                            headerBuilder:
                                (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) =>
                                    Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Text(
                                snapshot.data[i].category,
                              ),
                            ),
                            body: Column(
                              children: snapshot.data[i].subcategory.map((e) {
                                return Text(e);
                              }).toList(),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
```