# Flutter Navigation Drawer ExpansionTile not collapse previous opened options when next option get Selected

Tags: flutter

When I click on one option in the left drawer, then another already selected opened options should be get collapsed.

My question is somewhat related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48930372/flutter-collapsing-expansiontile-after-choosing-an-item), but I am facing this in drawer, not in body.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPEwM.png) is what I am facing.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please follow this guide on how to ask questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You have referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48930372/flutter-collapsing-expansiontile-after-choosing-an-item). Just use all the code from here and replace this, you will get what you want

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Drawer(
        child: new AppExpansionTile(
                key: expansionTile,
                title: new Text(this.foos),
                backgroundColor: Theme
                    .of(context)
                    .accentColor
                    .withOpacity(0.025),
                children: <Widget>[
                    new ListTile(
                        title: const Text('One'),
                        onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                                this.foos = 'One';
                                expansionTile.currentState.collapse();
                            });
                        },
                    ),
                    new ListTile(
                        title: const Text('Two'),
                        onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                                this.foos = 'Two';
                                expansionTile.currentState.collapse();
                            });
                        },
                    ),
                    new ListTile(
                        title: const Text('Three'),
                        onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                                this.foos = 'Three';
                                expansionTile.currentState.collapse();
                            });
                        },
                    ),
                ]
        ),
    );
}
```