# Controlling multiple widgets of same type while avoiding a list of GlobalKeys

Tags: flutter

I've been using a custom Expansion Tile widget to be able to control the expansion programmatically:

```dart
const Duration _kExpand = const Duration(milliseconds: 200);

class AppExpansionTile extends StatefulWidget {
    const AppExpansionTile({
        Key key,
        this.leading,
        @required this.title,
        this.backgroundColor,
        this.onExpansionChanged,
        this.children: const <Widget>[],
        this.trailing,
        this.initiallyExpanded: false,
    })
        : assert(initiallyExpanded != null),
            super(key: key);

    final Widget leading;
    final Widget title;
    final ValueChanged<bool> onExpansionChanged;
    final List<Widget> children;
    final Color backgroundColor;
    final Widget trailing;
    final bool initiallyExpanded;

    @override
    AppExpansionTileState createState() => new AppExpansionTileState();
}

class AppExpansionTileState extends State<AppExpansionTile> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
    AnimationController _controller;
    CurvedAnimation _easeOutAnimation;
    CurvedAnimation _easeInAnimation;
    ColorTween _borderColor;
    ColorTween _headerColor;
    ColorTween _iconColor;
    ColorTween _backgroundColor;
    Animation<double> _iconTurns;

    bool _isExpanded = false;

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _controller = new AnimationController(duration: _kExpand, vsync: this);
        _easeOutAnimation = new CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.easeOut);
        _easeInAnimation = new CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.easeIn);
        _borderColor = new ColorTween();
        _headerColor = new ColorTween();
        _iconColor = new ColorTween();
        _iconTurns = new Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 0.5).animate(_easeInAnimation);
        _backgroundColor = new ColorTween();

        _isExpanded = PageStorage.of(context)?.readState(context) ?? widget.initiallyExpanded;
        if (_isExpanded)
            _controller.value = 1.0;
    }

    @override
    void dispose() {
        _controller.dispose();
        super.dispose();
    }

    void expand() {
        _setExpanded(true);
    }

    void collapse() {
        _setExpanded(false);
    }

    void toggle() {
        _setExpanded(!_isExpanded);
    }

    void _setExpanded(bool isExpanded) {
        if (_isExpanded != isExpanded) {
            setState(() {
                _isExpanded = isExpanded;
                if (_isExpanded)
                    _controller.forward();
                else
                    _controller.reverse().then<void>((value) {
                        setState(() {
                            // Rebuild without widget.children.
                        });
                    });
                PageStorage.of(context)?.writeState(context, _isExpanded);
            });
            if (widget.onExpansionChanged != null) {
                widget.onExpansionChanged(_isExpanded);
            }
        }
    }

    Widget _buildChildren(BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        final Color borderSideColor = _borderColor.evaluate(_easeOutAnimation) ?? Colors.transparent;
        final Color titleColor = _headerColor.evaluate(_easeInAnimation);

        return new Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: _backgroundColor.evaluate(_easeOutAnimation) ?? Colors.transparent,
                border: new Border(
                    top: new BorderSide(color: borderSideColor),
                    bottom: new BorderSide(color: borderSideColor),
                )
            ),
            child: new Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                    IconTheme.merge(
                        data: new IconThemeData(color: _iconColor.evaluate(_easeInAnimation)),
                        child: new ListTile(
                            onTap: toggle,
                            leading: widget.leading,
                            title: new DefaultTextStyle(
                                style: Theme
                                    .of(context)
                                    .textTheme
                                    .subhead
                                    .copyWith(color: titleColor),
                                child: widget.title,
                            ),
                            trailing: widget.trailing ?? new RotationTransition(
                                turns: _iconTurns,
                                child: const Icon(Icons.expand_more),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    new ClipRect(
                        child: new Align(
                            heightFactor: _easeInAnimation.value,
                            child: child,
                        ),
                    ),
                ],
            ),
        );
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
        _borderColor.end = theme.dividerColor;
        _headerColor
            ..begin = theme.textTheme.subhead.color
            ..end = theme.accentColor;
        _iconColor
            ..begin = theme.unselectedWidgetColor
            ..end = theme.accentColor;
        _backgroundColor.end = widget.backgroundColor;

        final bool closed = !_isExpanded && _controller.isDismissed;
        return new AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: _controller.view,
            builder: _buildChildren,
            child: closed ? null : new Column(children: widget.children),
        );
    }
}
```

Now I can pass a `GlobalKey<AppExpansionTileState>` object to this widget to control its expansion:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new ExpansionTileTest());
}

class ExpansionTileTest extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GlobalKey<AppExpansionTileState> key = GlobalKey();

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('ExpansionTile Test'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Expand'),
              onPressed: () => key.currentState.expand(),
            ),
            AppExpansionTile(
              key: key,
              title: Text('My Tile'),
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('My Tile child'),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Here's the problem:** In my application, I'm using `AppExpansionTile` quite generously, and at places, they are nested within each other. I've been trying to implement `Expand All` and `Collapse All` functions for these views. When there are multiples of them on the same level, it's easy to pass:

```dart
List<GlobalKey<AppExpansionTileState>> keys = List();
```

and just say:

```dart
keys.forEach((k) => k.currentState.expand());
```

I'm not quite sure the approach above is good practice, but it works. However, it gets complicated when I have to expand all of these tiles when they are nested within each other, and the `GlobalKey` solution starts to look ugly (Example is simplified, normally I create the tiles using a `ListView.builder`):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new ExpansionTileTest());
}

class ExpansionTileTest extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<GlobalKey<AppExpansionTileState>> keys = List(6);
    keys.forEach((k) => k = GlobalKey());

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('ExpansionTile Test'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Expand All'),
              onPressed: () => keys.forEach((k) => k.currentState.expand()),
            ),
            AppExpansionTile(
              key: keys[0],
              title: Text('My Tile 1'),
              children: <Widget>[
                AppExpansionTile(
                  key: keys[1],
                  title: Text('My Child Tile 1'),
                ),
                AppExpansionTile(
                  key: keys[2],
                  title: Text('My Child Tile 2'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            AppExpansionTile(
              key: keys[3],
              title: Text('My Tile 2'),
              children: <Widget>[
                AppExpansionTile(
                  key: keys[4],
                  title: Text('My Child Tile 1'),
                ),
                AppExpansionTile(
                  key: keys[5],
                  title: Text('My Child Tile 2'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Is there an approach out there where you can use a single key to control multiple widgets assigned to it?

Side Note: AppExpansionTile was taken from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48935106/9488787. Thanks @Simon.

Comment: look good,  you can also use ***[provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)*** or ***[rxdart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart)***
, i recommand  ***[provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)*** , here some videos ***[Pragmatic State Management in Flutter (Google I/O'19) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_m5csmrf7I)***
 & ***[Pragmatic State Management Using Provider (The Boring Flutter Development Show, Ep. 24) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HrBiNHEqSYU)***

Comment: Hi Mohamed, thanks for the comment, but I don't see the relevance of provider to the issue at hand - could you elaborate?

Comment: my suggestion : is to make an observable variable shared between widgets and let the widgets subscribe to it , then send new values to the observable and all the listening widgets will react to new values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating a controller for the `AppExpansionTile`:

```dart
class AppExpansionTileController extends ValueNotifier<bool> {
  AppExpansionTileController(bool value) : super(value);

  void expand() {
    value = true;
  }

  void collapse() {
    value = false;
  }

  void toggle() {
    value = !value;
  }
}
```

and then added this controller to my `AppExpansionTile`:

```dart
const Duration _kExpand = const Duration(milliseconds: 200);

class AppExpansionTile extends StatefulWidget {
    const AppExpansionTile({
        Key key,
        this.leading,
        @required this.title,
        this.backgroundColor,
        this.onExpansionChanged,
        this.children: const <Widget>[],
        this.trailing,
        this.expansionController // Adding controller
    })
        : assert(initiallyExpanded != null),
            super(key: key);

    final Widget leading;
    final Widget title;
    final ValueChanged<bool> onExpansionChanged;
    final List<Widget> children;
    final Color backgroundColor;
    final Widget trailing;
    final AppExpansionTileController expansionController; // Adding controller

    @override
    AppExpansionTileState createState() => new AppExpansionTileState();
}

class AppExpansionTileState extends State<AppExpansionTile> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
    AnimationController _animationController;
    CurvedAnimation _easeOutAnimation;
    CurvedAnimation _easeInAnimation;
    ColorTween _borderColor;
    ColorTween _headerColor;
    ColorTween _iconColor;
    ColorTween _backgroundColor;
    Animation<double> _iconTurns;

    // Adding controller
    AppExpansionTileController _expansionController;
    AppExpansionTileController get _effectiveController => widget.controller ?? _expansionController;

    bool _isExpanded;

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _animationController= new AnimationController(duration: _kExpand, vsync: this);
        _easeOutAnimation = new CurvedAnimation(parent: _animationController, curve: Curves.easeOut);
        _easeInAnimation = new CurvedAnimation(parent: _animationController, curve: Curves.easeIn);
        _borderColor = new ColorTween();
        _headerColor = new ColorTween();
        _iconColor = new ColorTween();
        _iconTurns = new Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 0.5).animate(_easeInAnimation);
        _backgroundColor = new ColorTween();

        // If no controller was passed, we're creating our own controller with an initially collapsed state
        if (widget.controller == null) _expansionController = AppExpansionTileController(false);

        _isExpanded = _effectiveController.value;
        //Listening to the value from our controller to change expansion state.
        _effectiveController.addListener(() => _setExpanded(_effectiveController.value));
        if (_isExpanded) _animationController.value = 1.0;
    }

    @override
    void dispose() {
        _animationController.dispose();
        super.dispose();
    }

    void expand() {
        _setExpanded(true);
    }

    void collapse() {
        _setExpanded(false);
    }

    void toggle() {
        _setExpanded(!_isExpanded);
    }

    void _setExpanded(bool isExpanded) {
        if (_isExpanded != isExpanded) {
            setState(() {
                _isExpanded = isExpanded;
                if (_isExpanded)
                    _animationController.forward();
                else
                    _animationController.reverse().then<void>((value) {
                        setState(() {
                            // Rebuild without widget.children.
                        });
                    });
                PageStorage.of(context)?.writeState(context, _isExpanded);
            });
            if (widget.onExpansionChanged != null) {
                widget.onExpansionChanged(_isExpanded);
            }
        }
    }

    Widget _buildChildren(BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        final Color borderSideColor = _borderColor.evaluate(_easeOutAnimation) ?? Colors.transparent;
        final Color titleColor = _headerColor.evaluate(_easeInAnimation);

        return new Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: _backgroundColor.evaluate(_easeOutAnimation) ?? Colors.transparent,
                border: new Border(
                    top: new BorderSide(color: borderSideColor),
                    bottom: new BorderSide(color: borderSideColor),
                )
            ),
            child: new Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                    IconTheme.merge(
                        data: new IconThemeData(color: _iconColor.evaluate(_easeInAnimation)),
                        child: new ListTile(
                            onTap: toggle,
                            leading: widget.leading,
                            title: new DefaultTextStyle(
                                style: Theme
                                    .of(context)
                                    .textTheme
                                    .subhead
                                    .copyWith(color: titleColor),
                                child: widget.title,
                            ),
                            trailing: widget.trailing ?? new RotationTransition(
                                turns: _iconTurns,
                                child: const Icon(Icons.expand_more),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    new ClipRect(
                        child: new Align(
                            heightFactor: _easeInAnimation.value,
                            child: child,
                        ),
                    ),
                ],
            ),
        );
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
        _borderColor.end = theme.dividerColor;
        _headerColor
            ..begin = theme.textTheme.subhead.color
            ..end = theme.accentColor;
        _iconColor
            ..begin = theme.unselectedWidgetColor
            ..end = theme.accentColor;
        _backgroundColor.end = widget.backgroundColor;

        final bool closed = !_isExpanded && _animationController.isDismissed;
        return new AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: _animationController.view,
            builder: _buildChildren,
            child: closed ? null : new Column(children: widget.children),
        );
    }
}
```

Now I can create a single instance of my controller and control all `AppExpansionTile`s with it:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new ExpansionTileTest());
}

class ExpansionTileTest extends StatelessWidget {
  //Creating a controller with an initially collapsed state
  final AppExpansionTileController expansionController = AppExpansionTileController(false);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('ExpansionTile Test'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Expand All'),
              //Calling our controller's expand method
              onPressed: () => expansionController.expand(),
            ),
            AppExpansionTile(
              expansionController: expansionController,
              title: Text('My Tile 1'),
              children: <Widget>[
                AppExpansionTile(
                  expansionController: expansionController,
                  title: Text('My Child Tile 1'),
                ),
                AppExpansionTile(
                  expansionController: expansionController,
                  title: Text('My Child Tile 2'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            AppExpansionTile(
              expansionController: expansionController,
              title: Text('My Tile 2'),
              children: <Widget>[
                AppExpansionTile(
                  expansionController: expansionController,
                  title: Text('My Child Tile 1'),
                ),
                AppExpansionTile(
                  expansionController: expansionController,
                  title: Text('My Child Tile 2'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```