# How to collapse other ExpansionTile elements in Flutter

Tags: flutter, material-design

We have 3 sections of ExpansionTiles and on expanding one, the others should collapse. Quite easy... but:

was not able to find anything helpful in the flutter docs.
Anyone knows how to accomplish this?

Here is the example code from the Flutter doc pages. If you click on Chapter A, B and C should collapse (if visible) and also if you then click on Chapter B, A and C should be collapsing... ans so on.

Example-Code:

```
  // Copyright 2017 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
  // Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
  // found in the LICENSE file.

  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  class ExpansionTileSample extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('ExpansionTile'),
          ),
          body: ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                EntryItem(data[index]),
            itemCount: data.length,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  // One entry in the multilevel list displayed by this app.
  class Entry {
    Entry(this.title, [this.children = const <Entry>[]]);

    final String title;
    final List<Entry> children;
  }

  // The entire multilevel list displayed by this app.
  final List<Entry> data = <Entry>[
    Entry(
      'Chapter A',
      <Entry>[
        Entry('Section A1'),
        Entry('Section A2'),
      ],
    ),
    Entry(
      'Chapter B',
      <Entry>[
        Entry('Section B0'),
        Entry('Section B1'),
      ],
    ),
    Entry(
      'Chapter C',
      <Entry>[
        Entry('Section C0'),
        Entry('Section C1'),
      ],
    ),
  ];

  // Displays one Entry. If the entry has children then it's displayed
  // with an ExpansionTile.
  class EntryItem extends StatelessWidget {
    const EntryItem(this.entry);

    final Entry entry;

    Widget _buildTiles(Entry root) {
      if (root.children.isEmpty) return ListTile(title: Text(root.title));
      return ExpansionTile(
        key: PageStorageKey<Entry>(root),
        title: Text(root.title),
        children: root.children.map(_buildTiles).toList(),
      );
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return _buildTiles(entry);
    }
  }

  void main() {
    runApp(ExpansionTileSample());
  }
```

Source: [Flutter: ExpansionTile sample](https://flutter.dev/docs/catalog/samples/expansion-tile-sample)

Comment: Check this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48930372/flutter-collapsing-expansiontile-after-choosing-an-item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider [this answer in GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7024#issuecomment-578124918).

Check this sample:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'ExpansionTile Collapse',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'ExpansionTile Collapse'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  // selected's value = 0. For default first item is open.
  int selected = 0; //attention

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('ExpansionTile Collapse',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(children: [
            ListView.builder(
              key: Key('builder ${selected.toString()}'), //attention
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 13.0, right: 13.0, bottom: 25.0),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: 5,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Column(children: <Widget>[
                  Divider(
                    height: 17.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  ExpansionTile(
                    key: Key(index.toString()), //attention
                    initiallyExpanded: index == selected, //attention

                    leading: Icon(
                      Icons.person,
                      size: 50.0,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    title: Text('ExpansionTile ${index}',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xFF09216B),
                            fontSize: 17.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      'Software Engineer',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 13.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                        child: Text(
                          'DETAİL ${index} \n' + 'Expanded',
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                    onExpansionChanged: ((newState) {
                      if (newState)
                        setState(() {
                          Duration(seconds: 20000);
                          selected = index;
                        });
                      else
                        setState(() {
                          selected = -1;
                        });
                    }),
                  ),
                ]);
              },
            )
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Actual output:

[image]