# Expand one ExpansionTile close all others?

Tags: flutter

i'm having a problem with ExpanstionTile.

What i'm trying to do is when user click on one ExpansionTile, all others will collapse.

I build a ListView with map.keys and from each map[key] i build a ListView with value with that map[key] value.

My situation is i have multiple lists and the index is duplicate. So when i setState the selected = index the other expanstionTile opens as well

```
  /// ----#1
  Map<String, List<ExpansionObj>> map = {
    'A': [
      ExpansionObj('a', '1a', 'title 1'),
      ExpansionObj('aa', '2a', 'title 2'),
      ExpansionObj('aaa', '3a', 'title 3'),
    ],
    'B': [
      ExpansionObj('b', '4', 'title 4'),
      ExpansionObj('bb', '5', 'title 5'),
      ExpansionObj('bbb', '6', 'title 6'),
    ],
  };
```

The problem is when i set the selected = position of expansion "a", expansion b also open.
I read about Key but quite confuse how to use it.

```
setState(() {
  selected = position;
});
```

[image: ExpansionTile]

```
   ListView.builder(
      itemCount: map.keys.length,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('${map.keys.toList()[index]}'),
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: map[map.keys.toList()[index]].length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
                var obj = map[map.keys.toList()[index]][position];
                return ExpansionTile(
                  key: Key(''),
                  onExpansionChanged: (bool) {
                    if (bool) {
                      setState(() {
                        selected = position;
                      });
                    }
                  },
                  initiallyExpanded: selected == position ? true : false,
                  title: Text('${obj.objClass}'),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: map.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                        return Center(
                          child: Text('${obj.objTitle}'),
                        );
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter - Collapsing ExpansionTile after choosing an item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48930372/flutter-collapsing-expansiontile-after-choosing-an-item)

Comment: @hisam no, i tried. My situation is i have multiple lists and the index is duplicate. So when i setState the selected = index the other expanstionTile opens as well