# Flutter ExpansionTile Extention button placement

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a container which i want to expand one i click the down arrow button. If you look in this picture (https://gyazo.com/eeaa9fb8d3f93d5f6f190ced2389e2e1), you can see that i already added a button which i want to click so it will expand. But once i wrap the container in an expansiontile, it adds an arrow to the left of it as you can see in this picture (https://gyazo.com/c8ec072e511f7f0d03ff925c2d8f158d).

My code is here with the results in the second picture

```
Container(

    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.97,
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 20, right: 20),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xff0A213D),
        borderRadius:
        BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(3))),
    child: ExpansionTile(

        title: Column(children: < Widget > [

            Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: < Widget > [
                    Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                        child:
                        Text("Obiectiv numarul 1", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.white), ), ),
                    IconButton(
                        iconSize: 35,
                        color: Color(0xff6c7a8b),
                        icon: Icon(Icons.create_outlined),
                        onPressed: () {

                        },
                    ),
                ], ),
            Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: Text('5 dec 2020', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Color(0xffdadada)), )),
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
                color: Colors.white,
                child: StepProgressIndicator(

                    totalSteps: 5,
                    currentStep: 2,
                    size: 6,
                    selectedColor: Color(0xff2f80ed),
                    unselectedColor: Colors.grey,
                )
            ),
            Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: IconButton(
                    iconSize: 45,
                    color: Color(0xff2f80ed),
                    icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_outlined),
                    onPressed: () {

                    },
                )),

        ], ),
        children: < Widget > [
            Text('expanded text')
        ],
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Settings **trailing** parameter to `Container()` or `SizedBox()` would remove the 2nd arrow or you could set your `IconButton()` to be the **trailing**: of `ExpansionTile`

Comment: i did remove the arrow now and i wanted to ask if there is any way to set the onclick of the arrow to expand the box

Comment: I recently implemented a custom ExpansionTile class that should also work in this situation https://stackoverflow.com/a/48935106/7441113