# Collapsing an ExpansionTile when clicking on another ExpansionTile in a ListView that also contains ListTiles

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am currently trying to create a behavior for my drawer. I have a ListView with ExpansionTiles and normal ListTiles in-between the ExpansionTiles. If the user clicks an ExpansionTile it will open but when they select another ExpansionTile from the list, I would like it to collapse the previously open ExpansionTile. I know that ExpansionPanel.radio can be used to create this effect but it doesn't allow for regular ListTiles to be in the list as well. Anybody ever achieved this and can provide tips?

Simplified code:

```
bool newsExpanded = false;
bool weatherExpanded = false;


ExpansionTile(
  initiallyExpanded: weatherExpanded,
  textColor: Colors.black,
  iconColor: Colors.grey,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white38,
  title: Text(
    'Weather',
    style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  ),
  onExpansionChanged: (onChanged) {
    
    if (onChanged) {
      setState(() {
        newsExpanded = false;
        weatherExpanded = true;
      });
    }
  },
```

Both ExpansionTiles are the same code but with different bools.

Answer (score 2):

After reading many SO posts and answers on this particular topic after facing this problem myself today it seems like there currently is no direct way to achieve this.

There are two workarounds that I have seen in the different answers:

1. The approach you also wanted to use. However, the problem is that `initiallyExpanded` is actually only called once when the `ExpansionTile` is built the very first time in the `build` method. So even if you change the bools for `newsExpanded` and `weatherExpanded` using `setState()`, `initiallyExpanded` is not called a second time. You can however cause `initiallyExpanded` to be triggered again by building a new `ExpansionTile` as replacement for the original one. This can be achieved by adding `key: GlobalKey()` to the `ExpansionTile`. The downside however, is that you lose the animation for the Widget because instead of changing its state you replace it with a new Widget that already renders as fully expanded.
2. You can also build your own `ExpansionTile` as a `StatefulWidget`. Thus you can assign a state to it and trigger expansion updates. The code behind this concept is quite extensive for what you want to achieve. If you're interested in using this approach you can find more informations and the neccessary code in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48935106/8212944).

I hope a functionality for this might be added in the future. Until then I'd consider thouroughly whether the functionality is really integral to your application.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of booleans for each one of your ExpansionTiles that holds whether the tile is open or not, start with all set to false and then whenever one of the tiles are open set the associated index in the list to true and all other to false.

Comment: I've tried doing that many times and it doesn't actually update the ExpansionTiles. The values can be changed but nothing updates the tiles themselves.

Comment: Are you setting the new values in setState?.@DA_cloak

Comment: Yes. That is what I did.

Comment: Simplified code added to the initial post.