# How to collapse the ExpansionTile on button click? - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm opening up a form to enter the details and close it upon filling everything and submitting it, but only the trailing icon is getting changed, also I'm trying to set the changes in the `onExpansionChanged` but not reflecting in the UI.

**Updated Code**

```
Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: TextButton(
            child: Text(count.toString()),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => RegisterLetterBookedListScreen()));
            },
          ),
          backgroundColor: ColorConstants.kPrimaryColor,
          elevation: 0,
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            MotionToast.success(
              title: 'Amount to be Collected',
              titleStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              description: '\u{20B9} $amountToBeCollected',
              descriptionStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              layoutOrientation: ORIENTATION.LTR,
              animationType: ANIMATION.FROM_LEFT,
              width: 300,
            ).show(context);
          },
          child: Text(
            '\u{20B9} $amountToBeCollected',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                //Article Details
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    

                //Sender Details
                ExpansionTile(
                  key: GlobalKey(),
                  trailing: (senderExpansion == false)
                      ? Icon(
                          MdiIcons.toggleSwitchOffOutline,
                          size: 40,
                          color: Colors.black54,
                        )
                      : Icon(MdiIcons.toggleSwitchOutline, size: 40, color: Colors.red),
                  onExpansionChanged: (value) {
                      senderExpansion = value;
                  },
                  maintainState: true,
                  initiallyExpanded: senderExpansion,
                  title: Text(
                    'Sender Details',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: senderHeadingColor,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        letterSpacing: 1),
                  ),
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        CInputForm(
                          readOnly: false,
                          iconData: Icons.person,
                          labelText: 'Name *',
                          controller: senderNameController,
                          textType: TextInputType.text,
                          typeValue: 'Name',
                          focusNode: senderNameFocusNode,
                        ),
                        CInputForm(
                          readOnly: false,
                          iconData: MdiIcons.home,
                          labelText: 'Address *',
                          controller: senderAddressController,
                          textType: TextInputType.multiline,
                          typeValue: 'Address',
                          focusNode: senderAddressFocusNode,
                        ),
                        Card(
                          elevation: 0,
                          child: TypeAheadFormField(
                            textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueGrey),
                                controller: senderPinCodeCityController,
                                autofocus: false,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    prefixIcon: Icon(
                                      Icons.location_on_outlined,
                                      color: Colors.blueGrey,
                                    ),
                                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                                    filled: true,
                                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                    ),
                                    labelText: 'Pincode/Office Name *',
                                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                        color: ColorConstants.kAmberAccentColor),
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)))),
                            onSuggestionSelected:
                                (Map<String, String> suggestion) async {
                              senderPinCodeCityController.text = suggestion['pinCode']!;
                              senderCityController.text = suggestion['city']!;
                              senderStateController.text = suggestion['state']!;
                            },
                            itemBuilder: (context, Map<String, String> suggestion) {
                              return ListTile(
                                title: Text(suggestion['officeName']! +
                                    ", " +
                                    suggestion['pinCode']!),
                              );
                            },
                            suggestionsCallback: (pattern) async {
                              return await FetchPin.getSuggestions(pattern);
                            },
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value!.isEmpty) {
                                issPin = false;
                                isLoading = false;
                              }
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        Visibility(
                          visible: issPin == false ? senderPinCodeCityController.text.isEmpty ? true : false : false,
                          child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 17.0),
                                child: Text('Select a Pincode/Office name', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: ColorConstants.kPrimaryColor),),
                              )),
                        ),
                        Visibility(
                          visible:
                              senderPinCodeCityController.text.isEmpty ? false : true,
                          child: CInputForm(
                            readOnly: true,
                            iconData: Icons.location_city,
                            labelText: 'City',
                            controller: senderCityController,
                            textType: TextInputType.text,
                            typeValue: 'City',
                            focusNode: senderPinCodeFocusNode,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Visibility(
                          visible:
                          senderPinCodeCityController.text.isEmpty ? false : true,
                          child: CInputForm(
                            readOnly: true,
                            iconData: Icons.location_city,
                            labelText: 'State',
                            controller: senderStateController,
                            textType: TextInputType.text,
                            typeValue: 'City',
                            focusNode: senderPinCodeFocusNode,
                          ),
                        ),
                        CInputForm(
                          readOnly: false,
                          iconData: MdiIcons.cellphone,
                          labelText: 'Mobile Number',
                          controller: senderMobileNumberController,
                          textType: TextInputType.number,
                          typeValue: 'MobileNumber',
                          focusNode: senderMobileFocusNode,
                        ),
                        CInputForm(
                          readOnly: false,
                          iconData: MdiIcons.email,
                          labelText: 'Email',
                          controller: senderEmailController,
                          textType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                          typeValue: 'Email',
                          focusNode: senderEmailFocusNode,
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),

                //Addressee Details
                ExpansionTile(
                  trailing: (addresseeExpansion == false)
                      ? Icon(
                          MdiIcons.toggleSwitchOffOutline,
                          size: 40,
                          color: Colors.black54,
                        )
                      : Icon(MdiIcons.toggleSwitchOutline, size: 40, color: Colors.red),
                  onExpansionChanged: (value) {
                      addresseeExpansion = value;
                  },
                  maintainState: true,
                  title: Text('Addressee Details',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: addresseeHeadingColor,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          letterSpacing: 1)),
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        CInputForm(
                          readOnly: false,
                          iconData: Icons.person,
                          labelText: 'Name *',
                          controller: addresseeNameController,
                          textType: TextInputType.text,
                          typeValue: 'Name',
                          focusNode: addresseeNameFocusNode,
                        ),
                        CInputForm(
                          readOnly: false,
                          iconData: MdiIcons.home,
                          labelText: 'Address *',
                          controller: addresseeAddressController,
                          textType: TextInputType.multiline,
                          typeValue: 'Address',
                          focusNode: addresseeAddressFocusNode,
                        ),
                        Card(
                          elevation: 0,
                          child: TypeAheadFormField(
                            textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueGrey),
                                controller: addresseePinCodeCityController,
                                autofocus: false,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    prefixIcon: Icon(
                                      Icons.location_on_outlined,
                                      color: Colors.blueGrey,
                                    ),
                                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                                    filled: true,
                                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                    ),
                                    labelText: 'Pincode/Office Name *',
                                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                        color: ColorConstants.kAmberAccentColor),
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)))),
                            onSuggestionSelected:
                                (Map<String, String> suggestion) async {
                              addresseePinCodeCityController.text =
                                  suggestion['pinCode']!;
                              addresseeCityController.text = suggestion['city']!;
                              addresseeStateController.text = suggestion['state']!;
                            },
                            itemBuilder: (context, Map<String, String> suggestion) {
                              return ListTile(
                                title: Text(suggestion['officeName']! +
                                    ", " +
                                    suggestion['pinCode']!),
                              );
                            },
                            suggestionsCallback: (pattern) async {
                              return await FetchPin.getSuggestions(pattern);
                            },
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value!.isEmpty) {
                                isLoading = false;
                                isaPin = false;

                              }
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        Visibility(
                          visible: isaPin == false ? addresseePinCodeCityController.text.isEmpty ? true : false : false,
                          child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 17.0),
                                child: Text('Select a Pincode/Office name', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: ColorConstants.kPrimaryColor),),
                              )),
                        ),
                        Visibility(
                          visible: addresseePinCodeCityController.text.isEmpty
                              ? false
                              : true,
                          child: CInputForm(
                            readOnly: true,
                            iconData: Icons.location_city,
                            labelText: 'City',
                            controller: addresseeCityController,
                            textType: TextInputType.text,
                            typeValue: 'City',
                            focusNode: addresseePinCodeFocusNode,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Visibility(
                          visible: addresseePinCodeCityController.text.isEmpty
                              ? false
                              : true,
                          child: CInputForm(
                            readOnly: true,
                            iconData: Icons.location_city,
                            labelText: 'State',
                            controller: addresseeStateController,
                            textType: TextInputType.text,
                            typeValue: 'State',
                            focusNode: addresseePinCodeFocusNode,
                          ),
                        ),
                        CInputForm(
                          readOnly: false,
                          iconData: MdiIcons.cellphone,
                          labelText: 'Mobile Number',
                          controller: addresseeMobileNumberController,
                          textType: TextInputType.number,
                          typeValue: 'MobileNumber',
                          focusNode: addresseeMobileFocusNode,
                        ),
                        CInputForm(
                          readOnly: false,
                          iconData: MdiIcons.email,
                          labelText: 'Email',
                          controller: addresseeEmailController,
                          textType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                          typeValue: 'Email',
                          focusNode: addresseeEmailFocusNode,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),

                //Submit
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Center(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                          backgroundColor:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white),
                          shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueGrey)))),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        setState(() {
                          senderExpansion = !senderExpansion;
                          addresseeExpansion = !addresseeExpansion;
                        });
                        final ifPresent = await RegisterLetterTable()
                            .select()
                            .ArticleNumber
                            .equals(articleNumberController.text)
                            .toMapList();
                        if (ifPresent.isNotEmpty) {
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                            content: Text('Article already scanned'),
                            behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                          ));
                        } else {
                          if (articleNumberController.text.isEmpty) {
                            setState(() {
                              articleNumberFocusNode.requestFocus();
                            });
                          } else if (weightController.text.isEmpty) {
                            setState(() {
                              weightFocusNode.requestFocus();
                            });
                          } else if (insuranceCheck == true) {
                            if (insuranceController.text.isEmpty)
                              insuranceFocusNode.requestFocus();
                          } else if (valuePayableCheck == true) {
                            if (valuePayablePostController.text.isEmpty)
                              valuePayableFocusNode.requestFocus();
                          }

                          if (senderNameController.text.isEmpty ||
                              senderAddressController.text.isEmpty ||
                              senderPinCodeCityController.text.isEmpty) {
                            setState(() {
                              senderExpansion = true;
                            });
                            if (addresseeNameController.text.isEmpty ||
                                addresseeAddressController.text.isEmpty ||
                                addresseePinCodeCityController.text.isEmpty) {
                              setState(() {
                                addresseeExpansion = true;
                              });
                            } else
                              setState(() {
                                addresseeExpansion = false;
                              });
                          } else
                            senderExpansion = false;
                          if (addresseeNameController.text.isEmpty ||
                              addresseeAddressController.text.isEmpty ||
                              addresseePinCodeCityController.text.isEmpty) {
                            setState(() {
                              addresseeExpansion = true;
                            });
                          } else
                            setState(() {
                              addresseeExpansion = false;
                            });

                          if (formGlobalKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                            formGlobalKey.currentState!.save();

                            showDialog<void>(
                                context: context,
                                barrierDismissible: false,
                                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                  return ConformationDialog(
                                      articleNumber: articleNumberController.text,
                                      weight: weightController.text,
                                      prepaidAmount: prepaidAmountController.text,
                                      acknowledgement: acknowledgementCheck,
                                      insurance: insuranceCheck == true
                                          ? insuranceController.text
                                          : '',
                                      valuePayablePost: valuePayableCheck == true
                                          ? valuePayablePostController.text
                                          : '',
                                      amountToBeCollected:
                                          amountToBeCollectedController.text,
                                      senderName: senderNameController.text,
                                      senderAddress: senderAddressController.text,
                                      senderPinCode: senderPinCodeCityController.text,
                                      senderCity: senderCityController.text,
                                      senderState: senderStateController.text,
                                      senderMobileNumber:
                                          senderMobileNumberController.text,
                                      senderEmail: senderEmailController.text,
                                      addresseeName: addresseeNameController.text,
                                      addresseeAddress: addresseeAddressController.text,
                                      addresseePinCode:
                                          addresseePinCodeCityController.text,
                                      addresseeCity: addresseeCityController.text,
                                      addresseeState: addresseeStateController.text,
                                      addresseeMobileNumber:
                                          addresseeMobileNumberController.text,
                                      addresseeEmail: addresseeEmailController.text,
                                      function: () {
                                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                        printFunction();
                                      });
                                });
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: new Text(
                          'SUBMIT',
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: TextStyle(color: ColorConstants.kAmberAccentColor),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ))
```

Comment: Removing the ```Column``` widget from the ```ExpansionTile children``` will work

Comment: Nope not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your using Multiple ExpansionTiles, as said by @Jai Techie you need a **key** to control its state, but as per my knowledge we cannot provide the state of the ExpansionTile as the GlobalKey, so in order to acheive it create a new CustomExpansionTile.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class FormExpansionTileCard extends StatefulWidget {

  const FormExpansionTileCard({
    Key? key,
    this.leading,
    required this.title,
    this.subtitle,
    this.onExpansionChanged,
    this.children = const <Widget>[],
    this.trailing,
    this.borderRadius = const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
    this.elevation = 2.0,
    this.initialElevation = 0.0,
    this.initiallyExpanded = false,
    this.initialPadding = EdgeInsets.zero,
    this.finalPadding = const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 6.0),
    this.contentPadding,
    this.baseColor,
    this.expandedColor,
    this.expandedTextColor,
    this.duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
    this.elevationCurve = Curves.easeOut,
    this.heightFactorCurve = Curves.easeIn,
    this.turnsCurve = Curves.easeIn,
    this.colorCurve = Curves.easeIn,
    this.paddingCurve = Curves.easeIn,
    this.isThreeLine = false,
    this.shadowColor = const Color(0xffaaaaaa),
    this.animateTrailing = false,
  })  : assert(initiallyExpanded != null),
        super(key: key);

  final bool isThreeLine;
  final Widget? leading;
  final Widget title;
  final Widget? subtitle;
  final ValueChanged<bool>? onExpansionChanged;
  final List<Widget> children;
  final Widget? trailing;
  final bool animateTrailing;
  final BorderRadiusGeometry borderRadius;
  final double elevation;
  final double initialElevation;
  final Color shadowColor;
  final bool initiallyExpanded;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry initialPadding;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry finalPadding;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry? contentPadding;
  final Color? baseColor;
  final Color? expandedColor;
  final Color? expandedTextColor;
  final Duration duration;
  final Curve elevationCurve;
  final Curve heightFactorCurve;
  final Curve turnsCurve;
  final Curve colorCurve;
  final Curve paddingCurve;

  @override
  FormExpansionTileCardState createState() => FormExpansionTileCardState();
}

class FormExpansionTileCardState extends State<FormExpansionTileCard>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  static final Animatable<double> _halfTween =
  Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 0.5);

  final ColorTween _headerColorTween = ColorTween();
  final ColorTween _iconColorTween = ColorTween();
  final ColorTween _materialColorTween = ColorTween();
  late EdgeInsetsTween _edgeInsetsTween;
  late Animatable<double> _elevationTween;
  late Animatable<double> _heightFactorTween;
  late Animatable<double> _turnsTween;
  late Animatable<double> _colorTween;
  late Animatable<double> _paddingTween;

  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation<double> _iconTurns;
  late Animation<double> _heightFactor;
  late Animation<double> _elevation;
  late Animation<Color?> _headerColor;
  late Animation<Color?> _iconColor;
  late Animation<Color?> _materialColor;
  late Animation<EdgeInsets> _padding;

  bool _isExpanded = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _edgeInsetsTween = EdgeInsetsTween(
      begin: widget.initialPadding as EdgeInsets?,
      end: widget.finalPadding as EdgeInsets?,
    );
    _elevationTween = CurveTween(curve: widget.elevationCurve);
    _heightFactorTween = CurveTween(curve: widget.heightFactorCurve);
    _colorTween = CurveTween(curve: widget.colorCurve);
    _turnsTween = CurveTween(curve: widget.turnsCurve);
    _paddingTween = CurveTween(curve: widget.paddingCurve);

    _controller = AnimationController(duration: widget.duration, vsync: this);
    _heightFactor = _controller.drive(_heightFactorTween);
    _iconTurns = _controller.drive(_halfTween.chain(_turnsTween));
    _headerColor = _controller.drive(_headerColorTween.chain(_colorTween));
    _materialColor = _controller.drive(_materialColorTween.chain(_colorTween));
    _iconColor = _controller.drive(_iconColorTween.chain(_colorTween));
    _elevation = _controller.drive(
        Tween<double>(begin: widget.initialElevation, end: widget.elevation)
            .chain(_elevationTween));
    _padding = _controller.drive(_edgeInsetsTween.chain(_paddingTween));
    _isExpanded = PageStorage.of(context)?.readState(context) as bool? ??
        widget.initiallyExpanded;
    if (_isExpanded) _controller.value = 1.0;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  // Credit: Simon Lightfoot - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48935106/955974
  void _setExpansion(bool shouldBeExpanded) {
    if (shouldBeExpanded != _isExpanded) {
      setState(() {
        _isExpanded = shouldBeExpanded;
        if (_isExpanded) {
          _controller.forward();
        } else {
          _controller.reverse().then<void>((void value) {
            if (!mounted) return;
            setState(() {
              // Rebuild without widget.children.
            });
          });
        }
        PageStorage.of(context)?.writeState(context, _isExpanded);
      });
      if (widget.onExpansionChanged != null)
        widget.onExpansionChanged!(_isExpanded);
    }
  }

  void expand() {
    _setExpansion(true);
  }

  void collapse() {
    _setExpansion(false);
  }

  void toggleExpansion() {
    _setExpansion(!_isExpanded);
  }

  Widget _buildChildren(BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
    return Padding(
      padding: _padding.value,
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.grey[200],
        borderRadius: widget.borderRadius,
        elevation: 0,
        shadowColor: widget.shadowColor,
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              InkWell(
                customBorder:
                RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: widget.borderRadius),
                onTap: toggleExpansion,
                child: ListTileTheme.merge(
                  iconColor: _iconColor.value,
                  textColor: _headerColor.value,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                    child: ListTile(
                      isThreeLine: widget.isThreeLine,
                      contentPadding: widget.contentPadding,
                      leading: widget.leading,
                      title: widget.title,
                      subtitle: widget.subtitle,
                      trailing: RotationTransition(
                        turns: widget.trailing == null || widget.animateTrailing
                            ? _iconTurns
                            : AlwaysStoppedAnimation(0),
                        child: widget.trailing ?? Icon(Icons.expand_more),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ClipRect(
                child: Align(
                  heightFactor: _heightFactor.value,
                  child: child,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    _headerColorTween
      ..begin = theme.textTheme.subtitle1!.color
      ..end = widget.expandedTextColor ?? theme.accentColor;
    _iconColorTween
      ..begin = theme.unselectedWidgetColor
      ..end = widget.expandedTextColor ?? theme.accentColor;
    _materialColorTween
      ..begin = widget.baseColor ?? theme.canvasColor
      ..end = widget.expandedColor ?? theme.cardColor;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bool closed = !_isExpanded && _controller.isDismissed;
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _controller.view,
      builder: _buildChildren,
      child: closed ? null : Column(children: widget.children),
    );
  }
}
```

Initialize the key value in your dart file

```
  final GlobalKey<FormExpansionTileCardState> cardA = new GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey<FormExpansionTileCardState> cardB = new GlobalKey();
```

```
                //Sender Details
                FormExpansionTileCard(
                  key: cardA,
                  trailing: (senderExpansion == false)
                      ? Icon(
                          MdiIcons.toggleSwitchOffOutline,
                          size: 40,
                          color: Colors.black54,
                        )
                      : Icon(MdiIcons.toggleSwitchOutline, size: 40, color: Colors.red),
                  onExpansionChanged: (value) {
                      senderExpansion = value;
                  },
                  initiallyExpanded: senderExpansion,
                  title: Text(
                    'Sender Details',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: senderHeadingColor,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        letterSpacing: 1),
                  ),
                  children: [
                    //...Your Widgets
                  ],
                ),
                //Addressee Details
                FormExpansionTileCard(
                  key: cardB,
                  trailing: (senderExpansion == false)
                      ? Icon(
                          MdiIcons.toggleSwitchOffOutline,
                          size: 40,
                          color: Colors.black54,
                        )
                      : Icon(MdiIcons.toggleSwitchOutline, size: 40, color: Colors.red),
                  onExpansionChanged: (value) {
                      addresseeExpansion = value;
                  },
                  initiallyExpanded: addresseeExpansion,
                  title: Text(
                    'AddresseeDetails',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: senderHeadingColor,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        letterSpacing: 1),
                  ),
                  children: [
                    //...Your Widgets
                  ],
                ),
```

Answer (score 3):

checkout below code it may help you,

```
class TestExpanTile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  TestExpanTileState createState() => new TestExpanTileState();
}

class TestExpanTileState extends State<TestExpanTile> {

  String senderDet = 'Sender Details ';
  bool formOpenFlag = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: const Text('ExpansionTile'),
        ),
        body: new ExpansionTile(
          key: GlobalKey(),
          initiallyExpanded: formOpenFlag,
          onExpansionChanged: (val) {
            formOpenFlag = val; // update here on change
          },
          title: new Text(this.senderDet),
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor.withOpacity(0.025),
          children: <Widget>[
            new ListTile(
              title: const Text('Your Filling Form goes here'),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  formOpenFlag = !formOpenFlag;
                });
              },
              child: Text("Close Tile On Submit"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Still the same result in my end

Comment: have you changed the key  of ExpansionTile from key: expansionTile  To  key: GlobalKey(), @NaanAvan

Comment: Yes did change it but still it resulted in the same way, even did invalidate caches and restart but no use

Comment: can you please update the code which currently you tried?

Comment: It is working with `GlobalKey` but is it possible to get default animation while closing.

Comment: The key is working but I'm getting UI errors as I'm unable to access the textformfields inside the ExpansionTile widget, is it because I'm having two expansion tiles and i'm using the same key as ```GlobalKey()```

Answer (score 2):

I created a simple solution to this very problem. Hope this helps.

Solution: https://github.com/TreyThomas93/flutter-expansion-tile-demo

Comment: Link of solution does not consider as answer. Try to provide snippet within the post.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh did you look at the README. It literally explains in detail on how to implement this.

Comment: You can find more about [link-only-answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) and [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/1071764)