# ExpansionTile + SetState : How to keep tile state?

Tags: flutter

Hi currently I have a list screen composed of multiple ExpanstionTiles, upon click, the ExpansionTile reveals 2/3 Cards with Checkboxes.

Clicking in the checkbox triggers a SetState in the screen to save some files and update the Card (changing its colors for instance)

The issue is, whenever I click on a checkbox, the SetState builds the page again collapsing the ExpanstionTile.

I would like to keep the one that I am interacting opened, until I decide to close it again OR I go out of the page and go back.

I heard you could use Keys but I'm not so sure how. Currently I have a GlobalKey associated to the ExpantionTile to control a "scroll to view" with:

```
  void scrollToSelectedContent({required GlobalKey expansionTileKey}) {
    final keyContext = expansionTileKey.currentContext;
    if (keyContext != null) {
      Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 240)).then((value) {
        Scrollable.ensureVisible(keyContext,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200));
      });
    }
  }
```

and my ExpanstionTile looks like this:

```
return Card(
    child: ExpansionTile(
      key: expansionTileKey,
      initiallyExpanded: false,
      onExpansionChanged: (value) {
        if (value) {
          scrollToSelectedContent(expansionTileKey: expansionTileKey);
        }
      },
      leading: Text('t1'),
      title: Text('t2'),
      trailing: Text('t3'),
      subtitle: null,
      children: [
        ListView.builder(
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemBuilder: (context, index2) {
            //Code to create a card with checkbox and a SetState for the onPress
          },
          itemCount: 10,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
```

Comment: I'm not behind a Flutter environment right now, but when you use setState, it rebuilds the whole screen right? So when your initiallyExpanded parameter on Card widget is set to false, it takes that parameter again on rebuild (and is NOT expanded). You could turn that false into a separate bool which value you could store to true when you do your action inside the card.

Comment: yeah I thought about that too, but if I remove the initiallyExpanded or use a variable to control it, it applies to every single one of them in the list, not just the one being interacted with :(

Comment: have you tried ExpansionTileController(https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTileController-class.html) hope this will work

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48930372/flutter-collapsing-expansiontile-after-choosing-an-item

Comment: Im trying that right now but most of it seems outdated, so struggling even to get it compiling at the moment