# Collapse Expansion tiles when refreshing the page

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

When I refresh, the Expansion tiles remain opened, and I have to manually click to collapse it.

How do I collapse any opened `ExpansionTiles` when the `_handleRefresh` class is triggered?

Code Snippet:

```dart
ExpansionTile(
  title: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Text(
          data['branchName'],
          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
            fontSize: 16.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
          width: 60.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.6),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
            border: Border.all(
              color: Color(0xFFCDCDCF),
              width: 1.0,
            ),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                '${data['sstInService']} / ${data['totalSST']}',
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  fontSize: 12.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )),
      SizedBox(
        width: 20.0,
      )
    ],
  ),
  children: [
    Padding(
      padding:
          const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15.0, bottom: 10.0),
      child: const Divider(
          height: 10, thickness: 1.0, color: Color(0xFFCDCDCF)),
    ),

    ...buildTerminalContainer(getTerminalDataById(data['id']))
    //Terminal Information Based on Branch ID:
    // Text('Branch Name: ${data['id']}'),
    // Text('Branch Name: ${data['branchName']}'),
    // Text('Total SST: ${data['totalSST']}'),
  ],
),
```

```dart
Future<void> _handleRefresh() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)); // Simulating a delay

  setState(() {
    branchData =
        getAllBranch(); // Replace this with your actual refresh logic
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48930372/flutter-collapsing-expansiontile-after-choosing-an-item) for this.
You can add a `ExpansionTileController` and pass it to the expansionTile:

```dart
final _controller = ExpansionTileController();

ExpansionTile(
   controller: _controller,
   ...
)
```

and in your function called `_handleRefresh()` you can collapse it.

```dart
Future<void> _handleRefresh() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));

  setState(() {
    branchData = getAllBranch();
  });

  _controller.collapse(); // <-- this line
}
```